# Greatest Galois connection

Tags: order-theory, galois-connections

Let $\mathfrak{A}$, $\mathfrak{B}$ be bounded posets.

**The main question:** *Explicitly describe (and prove that it exists) the greatest Galois connection between $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ (as defined below).*

Consider Galois connections between these posets. Order them by the formula $f\le g \Leftrightarrow f^\ast\le g^\ast$ (where $f^\ast$ is the lower adjoint for a Galois connection $f$).

I am to find the greatest of all Galois connections between $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$. (This is my main question, how to describe this greatest connection.)

I conjecture that the greatest connection exists and its lower adjoint is defined by the formula:

$$f^\ast X = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  \bot^{\mathfrak{B}} & \text{if } X = \bot^{\mathfrak{A}}\\
  \top^{\mathfrak{B}} & \text{if } X \neq \bot^{\mathfrak{A}}
\end{array} \right.$$

($\bot$ denotes the least element of a poset and $\top$ the greatest one).

Please help to prove (or disprove) that the above defined $f^\ast$ is really a lower adjoint and help to find the corresponding upper adjoint.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what $f^\ast \leq g^\ast$ means (is it pointwise inequality?). But your $f^\ast$ does have an upper adjoint: namely, the map $\mathfrak{B} \to \mathfrak{A}$ sending $\top^{\mathfrak{B}}$ to $\top^{\mathfrak{A}}$ and all other elements of $\mathfrak{B}$ to $\bot^{\mathfrak{A}}$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, it is pointwise inequality

Comment: @darijgrinberg It seems that the map $\mathfrak{B} \to \mathfrak{A}$ you provided is not an upper adjoint of $f^\ast$. I am speaking about monotone Galois connections. Do you mean antitone ones?

Comment: Do you have a counterexample? I am talking of monotone connections as well.

Comment: @darijgrinberg See my updated question

Comment: What are $\alpha $ and $\beta $ ? We might have a misunderstanding as to what upper and lower mean (I prefer right and left).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Oh, I found I wrote $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by mistake. Now it is corrected

Comment: Your notion of a "lower adjoint" seems to be my notion of an "upper adjoint".

Comment: @darijgrinberg in $f^\ast x\leq y\Leftrightarrow x\leq f_\ast y$ we have $f^\ast$ being lower adjoint and $f_\ast$ being upper adjoint

Comment: But you are having it the other way round in your "routine verification".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @darijgrinberg:

Suppose $f^\ast$ has upper adjoint $f_\ast$. Then it is defined by the formula
$f_{\ast} Y = \max \left\{ X \in \mathfrak{A} \mid
f^{\ast} X \leq Y \right\} = \max \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  \mathfrak{A} & \text{if } Y = \top^{\mathfrak{B}}\\
  \{ \bot^{\mathfrak{A}} \} & \text{if } Y \neq \top^{\mathfrak{B}}
\end{array} \right. = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  \top^{\mathfrak{A}} & \text{if } Y = \top^{\mathfrak{B}}\\
  \bot^{\mathfrak{A}} & \text{if } Y \neq \top^{\mathfrak{B}}
\end{array} \right.$

Then the routine verification that they are indeed adjoint:

$f^\ast X \sqsubseteq Y \Leftrightarrow
X = \bot^{\mathfrak{A}} \land Y = \top^{\mathfrak{B}} \Leftrightarrow
X \sqsubseteq f_\ast Y$.